# How do I mock Jenkins job parameters in the test harness?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to use the test harness to test job dsl scripts: https://github.com/testcookbook/jenkins_harness

The seed Jenkins job has parameters configured for it and they can be accessed in the script like "${myparam}"

I run the seed jobs in spock like this though:

```
def 'test script #file.name'(File file) {
    given:
    def jobManagement = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))
    def myparam = 'sldkjflsdkjfs'
    // this also doesn't work (No such property: myparam for class: script)
    jobManagement.parameters.put("myparam", 'sldfjlsdjflskdjf')

    when:
    new DslScriptLoader(jobManagement).runScript(file.text)

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    where:
    file << jobFiles // uses groovy's automatic getter => getJobFiles()
}
```

The way the dsl scripts are loaded doesn't pick up "myparam". How and where can I set that so I can run this locally and set "myparam" to different values then will be configured on the actual seed job config?

Comment: did you find a solution?